# Where does sonarqube put the default widget?

Tags: sonarqube

I want to write my own plugin. I am not familiar with ruby on rails. I want to refer to the existing widget source code that coded by ruby. But How can I find them in the sonarqube folder?

[image: Below is my sonarqube folder structure]

For instance, where is the source code for the following widget?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look at SonarQube source code on GitHub, you will see that the Ruby templates for those widgets are located in a [the Core plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/tree/master/plugins/sonar-core-plugin/src/main/resources/org/sonar/plugins/core/widgets).

This means that those widget files are bundled in a JAR and deployed inside SonarQube installation folder. So you don't have a direct access to those files when installing SonarQube.